# Rename Excel file column names using ADOX

Tags: vba, excel, rename, adox

i am trying to pull in the field names from a closed Excel file using ADOX into a Dictionary object. However, some column names are ENCLOSED in Single quotes or some are just PREFIXED or SUFFIXED with a Single-quote.

> "'GLOBAL VIT/ACE'" OR  "'GLOBAL SAM/DUN" OR  "GLOBAL SUN SANDS'"

Now this is a cause of headache as i am unable to open a Recordset later and code is resulting in errors.

right now, when i try to rename the Fieldnames using ADOX, i get

> "Database is read-only"

so,

```
Set cols = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
i = 0
j = 0
blnSingleQuotes = False
For Each fld In objCat.tables(sSheet(1) & "$").Columns
    If InStr(1, "~" & UCase(fld.Name), "~" & UCase("Global")) > 0 Then
        cols.Add CStr(i), fld.Name
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf InStr(1, "~" & UCase(fld.Name), "~'" & UCase("Global")) > 0 Then
        If Right(UCase(fld.Name), 1) <> "'" Then
            fld.name=replace(fld.name,"'","")
            cols.Add CStr(i), fld.Name & "'"
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End If
next fld
```

My question is how do i remove them from the file using ADOX without opening the file? if not this way, then is there an alternative without opening file?

> P.S: I am not opening file because file takes time as it is very huge in size.